# How can a turn a list of dicts into a struct field column in pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

So basically I have a column called "my_views". This column looks like this:

| id | views |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{name=view1, id=0123-abc-4567}, {name=view2, id=9876-xyz-5432}] |
| 2 | [{name=view3, id=4589-adc-5467}, {name=view4, id=4476-add-5434}] |
| 3 | [{name=view5, id=6987-fha-4997}, {name=view6, id=9161-asd-1199}] |
| 4 | [{name=view7, id=0653-trt-4117}, {name=view8, id=9754-gfz-1222}] |

the column views is a string and I want to turn it into a struct type. How can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial step in your case is to turn the content of `views` column into a valid JSON and then parse it using [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html?highlight=from_json#pyspark-sql-functions-from-json) method. I've added a UDF that for that, that captures all relevant sections of the `views` string and adds double quotes so that it parses nicely (excuse my *parsing* logic - it's a bit sloppy and it needs refactor but I think it gives you a base to start from :)):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, ArrayType

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "[{name=view1, id=0123-abc-4567}, {name=view2, id=9876-xyz-5432}]"), (2, "[{name=view3, id=4589-adc-5467}, {name=view4, id=4476-add-5434}]")], "id: int, views: string")

schema = ArrayType(StructType([StructField("name", StringType()), StructField("id", StringType())]))

@udf(StringType())
def jsonize_string(string: str):
    return string \
        .replace("=", "\":\"") \
        .replace("[{", "[{\"") \
        .replace("}]", "\"}]") \
        .replace(", ", "\", \"") \
        .replace("}\", \"{", "\"}, {\"") \

display(df.withColumn("struct_views", from_json(jsonize_string(col("views")), schema=schema)))
```

[image]